# jquery check checkbox current time with other checkbox if current time are in start and end time? with checkbox group?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to check using checkbox group, and each checkbox have a start time and end time, I want to check if current checkbox when I try to checked, jquery would check the current time are in other checkbox for start and endt time or not? this is my try :

```
function checkcurrentgroup(g,t)
{
  //alert(g); is the group id  
  //alert(t); is the checkbox current time (start time)
  if($(':checkbox.' + g + ':checked').length > 0)
  {
      $(':checkbox.' + g + ':checked').each(function(i,e){    
        /*I don't know the code in here */      
      });      
  }  
}
```

this is the html code :

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="ids-1" id="ids-1" data-name="ids-1" value="ids-1-val" /></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="start" name="start" value="start1"/></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="end" name="end" value="start1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="ids-1" id="ids-1" data-name="ids-1" value="ids-1-val" /></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="start" name="start" value="start1"/></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="end" name="end" value="start1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="ids-2" id="ids-2" data-name="ids-2" value="ids-2-val" /></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="start" name="start" value="start2"/></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="end" name="end" value="start2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="ids-2" id="ids-2" data-name="ids-2" value="ids-2-val" /></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="start" name="start" value="start2"/></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="end" name="end" value="start2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="ids-3" id="ids-3" data-name="ids-3" value="ids-3-val" /></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="start" name="start" value="start3"/></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="end" name="end" value="start3"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="ids-3" id="ids-3" data-name="ids-3" value="ids-3-val" /></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="start" name="start" value="start3"/></td>
  <td><input type="hidden" id="end" name="end" value="start3"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Add your html code.

Comment: @Mohammad : thanks for reply mate, please check them again, already added the code.

Comment: @Mohammad : the current time only check based on the group checkbox, not in different group. :)

Comment: First your html isn't valid. You have multiple `#start` and `#end`. The code work in [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s9dw2xjg/)

Comment: @Mohammad : yeah you right mate, acctually I mean the #start and #end also different id.

Comment: @Mohammad : but I think it's no problem mate, I just check if current time are in ranges of #start and #end time in old checkbox (in the same group checkbox) then I have warning for that. it is right?

Comment: As i said in previous comment, there isn't any problem in code and loop work properly. But if you want to select element by id, you should have unique id.

Comment: ok mate, acctually I just changes the html code now, please check them mate, so what should I do for fix them? any suggestion?

Comment: hmm...I think you right I will try to changes them.